# node.js Q promise then chaining of promises

Tags: node.js, promise, q, chaining

the documentation says that chaining of promises works like

```
return getUsername()
  .then(function (username) {
     return getUser(username);
  })
  .then(function (user) {
```

wouldn't it be nice if the following would work as well?

```
return getUsername()
  .then(getUser)
  .then(function (user) {
```

I stumbled upon it because this is what I intuitively did and it didn't work.

thanks a lot

Comment: What's the definition of `getUser`? It looks good to me.

Comment: It's a function returning a promise. Like in the 1st example. And because it return a promise and not a value (e.g. user), it seems that it can not be used as parameter to then().

Comment: There is no difference in functionality between the two snippets you've posted.

Comment: @Bergi there is in some cases - see my answer below.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Ok, I believed OP who said that it's a function. It'll make a difference of course when it's `undefined` or a method :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works.

There are two reasons it might fail: variable vs function hoisting or dynamic `this`.

#### Hoisting and variable definitions.

A difference between:

```
var foo = bar;
```

And:

```
var foo = function(x){ return bar(x); }
```

Given it's bar's signature is that in the second snippet `bar` is lazily evaluated. So if `bar` is undefined you'll get an error in the first example but not the second. Most promise libraries ignore (and have to because of the specification) `undefined` passed to `then` and simply return the same promise.

This issue in your example might look like:

```
return getUsername()
  .then(function (username) {
     return getUser(username); // note it's a method
  })
  .then(function (user) { ...

// later on in the file after the function ended
var getUser = function(){
    // because of the function wrap above, this will work since 
    // the function(){ causes it to be lazily evaluated
};
```

On the other hand doing:

```
return getUsername()
  .then(getUser)
  .then(function (user) {

// later on in the file outside the function
var getUser = function(username){
       // code here
};
```

Is the same as doing:

```
return getUsername()
  .then(undefined) // remember, promises ignore this
  .then(function (user) {
```

This has to do with how JavaScript handles hoisting of variables vs. hosting of function declarations.

#### Dynamic this

The reason it's not working is that your code actually looks a bit different. Your code is more like:

```
return getUsername()
  .then(function (username) {
     return someObj.getUser(username); // note it's a method
  })
  .then(function (user) {
```

And in fact `getUser` is accessing `this` inside it - this makes this an unbound function which depends on `this`. Remember that JavaScript has dynamic `this` so you can't simply do:

```
return getUsername()
  .then(someObj.getUser) // this won't work, pun intended
  .then(function (user) {
```

Now, in order to make it work - you can bind it for example:

```
return getUsername()
  .then(someObj.getUser.bind(someObj) // IE9+
  .then(function (user) {

// if using bluebird, this is faster:
return getUsername().bind(someObj)
  .then(someObj.getUser) 
  .then(function (user) {
```

Or use the longer version with the function expression.

This might not be your specific issue - but 9 out of 10 times someone asks this - it solves their problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. "Hoisting and variable definitions" was the problem in my real code.

Comment: @Juergen glad I could help - for what it's worth in the soon coming version 3.0 bluebird promises will actively warn you in debug mode when you do this.